# How to Keep track of Mail recipients in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I would try to put a brief idea of the part i'm confused with,

In my rails application,
when i create a particular assignment ,few persons are included as a part.

Next the assignment goes to higher level and is approved by the chief,simultaneously email is sent to respective persons involved or included.

Now if i as a chief again disapprove and approve the assignment for some reason,then the persons should not get mails as already they received when first time the assignment was approved.

So i would like to know how to put a check on this?

Thanx

Comment: Can you explain how are you approving any assignment and sending mail? I want to know that r u setting some flag in assignment row?

Comment: 1.I as manager create a project and after creation it goes to pending approval state.

Comment: 1.Chief approved the project and so i receive a mail in return along with my fellows on that proejct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have to send mail after first approval not after that.
If you have any flag attribute in the assignments table then just set it null by default.
And in you callback method just check if flag attribute was null then send mail otherwise not.
Hope it will work.